# Migrate only woocommerce data to another woocommerce website

Tags: woocommerce, migration, backup

i have a woocommerce website which is up and running, i've made a new installation of woocommerce website on another server, and migrating products/orders/customers/product categories, I've tried all plugins and options, the issue is, that I'm using a plugin namely Extra product option by **"WooCommerce Extra Product Options By ThemeComplete"** while migrating products it doesn't migrate Extra product options data with it, there are almost 10,000 products on my website, i want to migrate all the images and data to another website, not willing to migrate wordpress data, but only the Woocommerce data, Thanks

Comment: Ask the plugin devs ? What i would do is to copy the entire website and clear w/e i dont need. I have done it many times and its about 1-2 hours of clearing depending on the size of content you want to remove.

Comment: how can I find unused images from a website and remove them? there's 60GB data i want just want the images of 9k products which are live right now, we've deleted many products and their data is still available in uploads folder, Thanks